# Change linetype for loess smooth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following [data](http://codeshare.io/gOV8H) that I want to plot using the LOESS smoother in ggplot2. The code below works fine to graph it, but I cannot find how to change the linetype for the LOESS line.

```
dat_int <- as.data.frame(read.csv("user_interactions.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE))
qplot(interactions, accurate, data=dat_int, geom=c('smooth'), method='loess')
```

I've tried the following, which doesn't work.

```
ggplot(dat_int, aes(x=interactions, y=accurate, linetype=5))
+ stat_smooth(size=1.5, method = "loess", level = 0.95, 
              fullrange = TRUE, se = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ggplot(dat, aes(interactions, accurate)) +
  geom_smooth(lty=2)  # or stat_smooth(lty=2)
```